# Excel formula to extract number from a alphanumeric cell with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am unable to come up with a formula to add extract only number from "Time"(Kindly refer to the attached Data set) in the picture attached.
If I had just string as minutes in my data set I was able to use SUBSTITUTE function to extract number but in the data set I have it usually has Hour or Minutes and I am not able to come up with a formula that does meets the condition below

- If 'Time' has 'Minutes' remove minutes and display number
- If 'Time' has 'Hour' in it multiple the number by 60

End result is I do not wish to manually use SUBSTITUTE function by filtering hour and minute separately to add Count + Time.

[image: Sample Data Set]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no further diversity within possible substring:

```
=A2+IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(B2," Hour","")*60,SUBSTITUTE(B2," Minutes",""))
```

Comment: If I have to add another substring how do I proceed. 
Hour = * 60
Minutes = Same value as above
Hours = * 60  (New substring)